# Custom Name Data Tags with /summon

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am currently making a map where all the mobs have names. While beta-testing, I summoned a magma cube named "Limus" with this command:

`/summon LavaSlime ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"Limus",Size:0.5}`

(in the 1.8 snapshot 14w06b)

Things seemed to work. Except, when I walked away from the slime I could still see the name tag, even when not looking at it. The same thing happened in 1.7.4 once (but I can't remember specifics) - which means it's not 1.8's fault.

I have a map in 1.7 which summons named zombies, and they only show their names when you look at them within a certain distance. What data tag would I add to make it so that the magma cube (or any other mob) would only show their name within a certain distance and when you look at them?

PS 40k question! :D

Comment: Btw, I recited the command from memory. If I got it wrong I'll edit my question.

Comment: Who needs names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set CustomNameVisible (byte) to True (1)

Comment: I misread the question, you want that to be false (0)

Comment: Oh, it's a boolean? I thought it was a value that determined something about the distance the mob's name was viewable from...

Comment: Not really, it's a byte that is either a 1 or 0, NBT does not have a boolean type....

Comment: Well, by boolean I meant a 0 or 1 value. Same difference. (PS Aren't there booleans in the /tellraw command? ("bold":"true", etc...))

Comment: Oh, but is that considered NBT? I don't think so. I take that back. What's the difference between NBT and other things that go in {}?